# Tailwind CSS not applying to mapped component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to map an array and limit to show 4 times the same component. The problem is that whenever I refresh the page the styling of the grid section goes away until I change one of the tailwind classes inside it. Here's my code:

```html
<div className={`suggested-file-gallery ${space_grotesk.className} ml-[31px] mr-[33px] mb-[20px]`}>
      <section className="flex items-center text-secondarytxt mt-[14px] mb-[10px]">
        Suggested
      </section>
      <section className="w-full grid grid-cols-suggested-files gap-4 auto-rows-[181px]">
        {files.length === 0 ? 
          <SuggestedFile id={"placeholder"} placeholder={true}/>
        : 
        files.slice(0, 4).map((file,index)=>{
          if (index <= 3) {
            return <SuggestedFile key={index} id={String(index)} placeholder={false}/>;
          }
          return <></>;
        })}
      </section>
    </div>
```

And this is the SuggestedFile component:

```html
 <div
    ref={fileRef} 
    className="individual-file-container rounded-[19px] 
                shadow-custom flex flex-col h-[181px]"
    onClick={(event) => {
      if (!placeholder) {
        handleFileSelection(event);
      }
    }}>
      {placeholder ? 
        <div className="w-64 h-full bg-[#E6E6E6] rounded-[19px] flex flex-col">
          <section className="flex-grow">

          </section>
          <section className="h-[25%] w-full inline-flex text-gray-500
                              items-center justify-center font-bold"> 
            Start creating files !
          </section>
        </div>
      :
      <>
        <section className={`flex-grow rounded-tr-[19px] rounded-tl-[19px]
        ${selectedFiles.includes(id) ? 'bg-[#F67E4B1A]': 'bg-white'}`}>
        </section>
        <section className="h-11 bg-[#E6E6E6] rounded-bl-[19px] w-full
              rounded-br-[19px] text-sm flex items-center justify-center">
          <div className="w-[90%] whitespace-nowrap overflow-hidden text-ellipsis">
            RAXHACKS JAVA GOD - proyecto unificatorio del rieles
          </div>
        </section>
      </>
      }
    </div>
```

The `grid-cols-suggested-files` is a custom tailwind class I created:

```json
gridTemplateColumns: {
        // Complex site-specific column configuration
        'suggested-files': 'repeat(auto-fill, minmax(256px,1fr))',
      }
```

I don't know what is going on. Before adding this grid, I wanted to just show the suggested section just if the files.length>0 and also the styling was a problem, that's why I added a placeholder.